# Investigate why package.json is displayed under /package.json

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gulp

I'm sorry if I don't provide any relevant code here but I need help where to investigate why package.json is displayed in development and production under http/https://[SITE]/package.json.

It's a simple react app and we use webpack.

Hopefully someone can tell me where to look!

See image:
[image]

Comment: Good places to start will be the webpack config and the configuration of whatever it is that is actually serving the files over http.

Comment: @mbojko I will look into the webpack files, thanks for the tip! This is a project I've just got handed over to me :)